# Check single column for multiple values mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table 'optionsproducts' having the following structure and values

```
ID      OptionID      ProductID
1       1             1
1       2             1
1       3             1
1       2             2
1       2             3
1       3             3
```

Now I want to extract ProductIDs against which both OptionID 2 and OptionID 3 is assigned. Which means in this case ProductID 1 and 3 should be returned. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get `productID`s which relate to both 2 and 3 `OptionId`s, you can write a similar query:

```
select productid
  from ( select productid
              , optionid
              , dense_rank() over(partition by productid 
                                  order by optionid) as rn
           from t1
          where optionid in (2,3)
        ) s
where s.rn = 2
```

Result:

```
PRODUCTID
----------
1
3
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d1ee3/3)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ID INT
    , OptionID INT
    , ProductID INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (ID, OptionID, ProductID)
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1),(1, 2, 1),
    (1, 3, 1),(1, 2, 2),
    (1, 2, 3),(1, 3, 3),(1, 3, 3)

SELECT ProductID
FROM @temp
WHERE OptionID IN (2,3)
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Output -

```
ProductID
-----------
1
3
```

Comment: I already tried that. This also returns ProductID 2. where as I need the query to return ProductID 1 and 3. The thing is I need ProductIDs against which both optionid 2 and optionid 3 is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID FROM table WHERE OptionID IN(2,3);
```

Comment: I want to extract ProductIDs against which both OptionID 2 and OptionID 3 is assigned. Your query will also return ProductID 2, where as my requirement is returning ProductID 1 and 3

Answer (score 0):

using distinct on (column-name) order by column-name.

```
select distinct on (column_name) require field order by that column name
```